# elasticsearch search for large text has "too many clauses"

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a set of news articles that I'm trying to index.  Sometimes I get the same article with a tiny change (e.g. "Sep" vs "September").  Before loading an article to the database, I'd like to see if there is anything really similar before I load it.

so I tried this (using the python elasticsearch_dsl library)

```
search = elasticsearch_dsl.Search(index=INDEX, doc_type=DOC_TYPE)
search = search.filter(match, text=article_text)
```

and that works for a bit, until I get a very long article.  Then I get an error message saying "maxClauseCount is set to 1024".

okay, so maybe my text is too long. So i do this:

```
text_bits = article_text.split()
if len(text_bits) > 1024:
   article_text = " ".join(text_bits[:1023])
```

and that works for the first item with lots of text, but not the second. So maybe my original guess is off, or maybe I'm not doing this right.

(incidentally, I see that there's "more like this" query listed in the documentation, but when I try to use it through Sense, like so:

```
post /myindex/article/_search
{
  "more_like_this" : {
    "fields" : ["text"],
    "like" : "mary had a little lamb"
  }
}
```

I get "unknown search element 'more_like_this'"

Comment: In Sense, you need to enclose `more_like_this` inside a `query: {}`. With py-dsl, you should be able to run `search.filter('more_like_this', ...)`